# ¿Como evitar doble click en una animación?

Tags: jquery

Veamos primero el código:

```js
$(function(){ 
  
  $('a').on('click', function() {    
    
      $('#box').slideToggle();
    
    }).dblclick(function(e) {
    
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;    
    });  
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#box {  
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
}

a {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a::selection {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="box"></div>
</div>
  
<a>Click me</a>
```

El problema lo vemos, si hacemos un doble click.

Ahí aparece y desaparece al momento la animación y lo que quiero es evitar que desaparezca.

Como se ve, he probado con el siguiente código:

```
.dblclick(function(e) {    
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;    
});
```

que lo he encontrado por algún sitio, pero no me funciona.

Tampoco puedo usar el controlador [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) ya que necesito que opere más de una vez.

¿Como se puede evitar el doble click en una animación en `jQuery`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He podido solucionar el problema usando [`.is(':animated')`](https://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/) y evitar así el doble click cuando este en plena *animación*.

```js
$(function(){ 
  
  $('a').on('click', function() {    
    
      if ($('#box').is(':animated')) {
        
        return false;
        
      } else {
      
        $('#box').slideToggle();
      }
       
    });  
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#box {  
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
}

a {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a::selection {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="box"></div>
</div>
  
<a>Click me</a>
```

*P.D. Estoy dispuesto de ver otras/mejores respuestas que puedan solucionar este problema*

Answer (score 1):

Pues he encontrado una manera, pero no se si te valdrá, es cambiar la etiqueta `<a>` por un boton:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#btnSubmit").on('click', function (event) {  
          $('#box').slideToggle();
           //event.preventDefault();
           var el = $(this);
           el.prop('disabled', true);
           setTimeout(function(){el.prop('disabled', false); }, 1000);
     });
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#box {  
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
}

a {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a::selection {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="box"></div>
</div>
  
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" >
```

El problema es que el elemento `<a>` no se puede desactivar, o por lo menos no funciona. Lo comentan en el siguiente enlace [Stack Ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085584/disable-a-hyperlink-using-jquery).

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta pero no puedo usar un botón... porque el elemento `<a>` ocupa toda la pantalla... funciona como un `esc`... no se si me explico :)... pero creo que he encontrado una solución... estoy aún aquí de pruebas...

Answer (score 0):

No sé si hay algún inconveniente con esta forma simple:

```js
var oneclick = true;
  $('a').on('click', function() {    
    if (oneclick) {
      $('#box').slideToggle();
      oneclick = false;
      }
    });
```

```css
#container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#box {  
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
}

a {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a::selection {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="box"></div>
</div>
  
<a>Click me</a>
```

La otra opción, no usar `slideToggle`.

```js
  $('a').on('click', function() {    
      $('#box').slideDown();
    });
```

```css
#container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#box {  
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
}

a {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a::selection {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="box"></div>
</div>
  
<a>Click me</a>
```

Comment: Es que necesito que opere más de una vez... lo que haz hecho es equivalente al evento [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/).. Gracias de todas formas