# Trackpads, prevenir multiscroll

Tags: jquery

Tengo un pequeño problema con los trackpads (al menos con los ratones de MAC).

Muestro el siguiente código actual:

```
$("body").on("mousewheel", function(e) {
    var body = $(this);
    //If the body doesn't have the "animating" class, we add it and do the animations here,
    //If it has it, it doesn't does anything until it finishes animating
    if(!body.hasClass("animating")) {
        body.addClass("animating");
        //MY CODE GOES HERE
        ...
        setTimeout(function() {
            body.removeClass("animating");
        }, 1500);
    }
});
```

Lo que hago con este trozo de código, es que cuando alguien haga scroll en la página, muestro unas animaciones, y hasta que estas no terminen, previene que se haga scroll de nuevo.

Esto funciona como anillo al dedo en los ratones convencionales con rueda, pero no con los trackpads. Si hago scroll rápidamente, una vez ha terminado las animaciones (y elimina la clase "animating" después de los 1500ms del setTimeout), vuelve ha hacer scroll y entra en la condición `if`, aunque no toque para nada el trackpad. Es como si el trackpad dejara en el stack muchos scrolls durante un periodo de tiempo dependiendo de lo rápido que haya hecho scroll

¿Hay alguna manera de prevenir este comportamiento?

**Añado para aclarar una cosita.** La página ocupa el 100% de la pantalla, es decir, no tiene scroll vertical, por lo tanto, la función `on("scroll", function())` no detecta el scroll.

Comment: has probado usando `.on('scroll', function() {` en vez de `mousewheel`? (Yo no puedo probarlo, no tengo trackpad)

Comment: no puedo usar scroll básicamente porque la página es lo que ocupa la pantalla. y dependiendo de la dirección donde se haga el scroll, hace unas animaciones u otras. `on("scroll", function() {})` necesita de hacer scroll necesariamente, por lo que no me indica si hago un scroll hacia arriba o hacia abajo

Comment: Gracias, pero no funciona, la página esa tiene un scroll vertical, y eso hará que si detecte la función scroll. Si haces que esos canvas sean de 50 por ejemplo, no lo detecta, lo acabo de probar

Comment: mhhh ok.. sigo pensando pues.

Comment: @Cheshire he estado probando y al menos con mi trackpad y mis dos diferentes mouses funciona correctamente o.O hice este simple [codepen](http://codepen.io/Naos/pen/EWLqmd?editors=0010) para probar

Comment: @Jorius Hola, gracias por tu tiempo, pero ocurre lo mismo. Si hago un scroll rápido (al menos con el ratón de MAC que es touch), la función de añadir la clase "animating" salta dos veces

Comment: No se si te valga pero puedes detectar si esta en proceso la animación, si esta en proceso evitar que se active nuevamente la animación algo así como [esta respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/39045/6635)

Comment: @JuankGlezz hola, ¿el `:animated` también captura animaciones de CSS3? ¿o solamente animaciones realizadas por javascript como jquery?

Comment: @Cheshire acabo de hacer unas pruebas y veo que no las captura, he investigado sobre las animaciones CSS3 y en [MDN encontré esto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations#The_HTML) acomodando a tu problema seria agregar `eventListener` y detectarlos en tu código que colocas aquí